# What does "this" refer to

Tags: javascript

what is the **this** (inside inner functions) referring to in the following code context? Does it point to TimeSpan?

```
var TimeSpan = function (days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) {
var attrs = "days hours minutes seconds milliseconds".split(/\s+/);

var gFn = function (attr) { 
    return function () { 
        return this[attr]; 
    }; 
};

var sFn = function (attr) { 
    return function (val) { 
        this[attr] = val; 
        return this; 
    }; 
};
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In this example `this` doesn't refer to anything, since none of these functions are ever executed. `this` depends on how a function is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `this` value is set **implicitly** depending on **how the function is invoked**, there are three cases where this happens:

1. When a reference with no base-object, or a non-reference is invoked:

   ```
   myFn();             // the myFn reference has no base object
   (function () {})(); // non-reference
   ```

   The `this` value will point to the global object <sup>**1**</sup>
2. When a reference contains a base object, for example:

   ```
   myObj.method();
   ```

   The `this` value inside `method` will point to `myObj`.
3. When the `new` operator is used:

   ```
   var obj = new Foo();
   ```

   The `this` value inside the `Foo` function, will point to a newly created object that inherits from `Foo.prototype`.

The `this` value can be set also **explicitly**, by using the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) methods, for example, with `call`:

```
function test(a) {
  return alert(this + a);
}

test.call("hello", " world"); // alerts "hello world"
```

Or with `apply` if we need to "apply" a set of arguments from an array to a function:

```
function test(a, b) {
  return alert(this + a + b);
}

var args = ["my ", "world "];
test.apply("hello ", args); // alerts "hello my world"
```

---

**<sup>[1]</sup>** This has changed on the new [ECMAScript 5th Strict Mode](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-2-strict-mode/), now when a function reference with no *base object*, or a non-reference is invoked (as the first case), the `this` value will contain `undefined`.

This was made because when working with constructor functions, people often forgot to use the `new` operator when calling the constructor.

When that happened, the `this` value pointed to the global object, and that ended up adding unwanted global properties.

Now on strict mode, `this` will contain undefined, and if property lookup is made on it (`this.foo = 'foo'`) we will have a nice `TypeError` exception, instead of having a global `foo` property.

Comment: Excellent explanation, couldn't have said it better or clearer :)

Comment: You certainly know your stuff!

Comment: Thanks guys!, @Marcus, I simply love this language :) `alert( true <3 );`

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the current object, in this case the function you are inside of. Since everything in JavaScript is an object you can modify the attributes of a function object using the `this` keyword:

```
var f = function() {
    this.key = "someValue";
}

console.log(f.key); // prints "someValue"
```

So in this case `this` should point to the function at the deepest scope level, and not `TimeSpan`.