# Scope of self-invocation function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does self-invocation function inside a function don't get the scope of the outer function in JavaScript?

```
var prop = "global";

var hash = {
    prop: "hash prop",
    foo: function(){
        console.log(this.prop);
        (function bar(){
            console.log(this.prop);
        })();
    }
};

var literal = {
    prop: "object"
};

hash.foo();
// hash prop
// global

hash.foo.call(literal);
// object
// global
```

Looks like altering the scope of the outer function has no effect on the scope of the inner self-invocation function.

PS: The question is not about how to alter the scope of the inner function. But what is the proper explanation in the "Javascript language" perspective? Does all self executing functions have 'global' scope by default? If so, why?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is the `this` and what it references:

```
foo: function(){
    console.log(this.prop);
    (function bar(){
        console.log(this.prop);  <--- this does not reference to foo here, but instead it refers to the window object
    })();
}
```

You need to keep a reference to the outer `this`:

```
foo: function(){
    console.log(this.prop);

    var that = this;
    (function bar(){
        console.log(that.prop);  <--- tada!
    })();
}
```

**Update**
Some explanation. It's all about how JavaScript determines the context when invoking a function.

```
function Test() {
    this.name = "Test";
    this.bar = function() { console.log("My name is: "+ this.name);}
}

function Blub() {
    this.name = "Blub";
    this.foo = function() { console.log("My name is: " + this.name);}
} 

var a = new Test();
var b = new Blub();

// this works as expected
a.bar(); // My name is: Test
b.foo(); // My name is: Blub

// let's do something fun
a.foo = b.foo; // make an educated guess what that does...

a.foo() // My name is: Test
```

Huh? Aren't we referencing the `method` of Blub? No we're not. We are referencing the unbound `function` of Blub.

JavaScript binds on `.` (dots) and based on that it decides waht the value of `this` should be.

Since you're not calling your anonymous function on an object (therefore no `.`) it will make `this` reference to the global object, which is - in case of the browser - the window object.

Another example (one might think this would work):

```
var str = "Hello World";
var ord = str.charCodeAt; // let's make a little shortcut here.... bad idea

ord(0) // no dot...
```

Instead of the char codes that are in `str` we get the ones that are in the global object, of course that's not a string so `charCodeAt` calls `toString` on which results in `"[object DOMWindow]"`

Comment: `this` will refer to the global object, not to `bar`. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223001/what-does-this-refer-to/4223037#4223037).

Comment: @CMS Yeah small black out here, it's quite late, fixed it.

Comment: In your first example this do not references "bar". It references your root object (the window object if you are inside a web browser)

Answer (score 1):

You are not applying any object as the `this` context when you call the inner function, so it gets `this` set to `window` by default.  If you wanted to call the closure with the same `this` as the outer function, you would have to do:

```
(function bar(){
    console.log(this.prop);
}).call(this);
```

Or:

```
var that = this;
(function bar(){
    console.log(that.prop);
})();
```