# How can a backbone model trigger an event from an Ajax Result?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following situation:

```
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
    },
    save: function() {
        $.ajax({
           type    : "POST",
           url     : "/api/savetask",
           data    : this.toJSON(),
           success : function (response) {
           this.trigger("something", "payload");
           }
         });
    }
});
```

When I run this, I get the following error

> `this.trigger` is not a function

On the external approach, I can trigger stuff.. like

```
var task = new Task();
task.trigger("something","payload");
```

What I am doing wrong? or not doing :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` in the anonymous function refers to the ajax object. This is because "this" in javascript changes with respect to the scope of the function. In order to reference "this" of the initial function, assign it to a different variable. The following will work:

```
save: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "/api/savetask",
        data    : this.toJSON(),
        success : function (response) {
            self.trigger("something", "payload");
        }
    });
}
```

*EDIT*: See [an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4223037/360705) of how "this" is determined.

Comment: other option would be to bind this to what you want it to be, so _(function(response) { ... }).bind(this)

Answer (score 7):

Personally I prefer having a `saveSuccess` method on the model.

```
    save: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "/api/savetask",
            data    : this.toJSON(),
            success : this.saveSuccess
        });
    },
    saveSuccess: function(response) {
        this.trigger("something", "payload");
    }
```

Comment: When I try this, `this` inside `saveSuccess` is still the XHR object rather than the model.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but in case anyone else happens upon this page: there is a much better way. Using the self object (in my experience) is considered a bit of an anti-pattern, since we use underscore.js and have access to the `bind` function. Anyway, here's a better way:

```
var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
    },
    save: function() {
        $.ajax("/api/savetask", {
           type    : "POST",
           data    : this.toJSON(),
           context : this,
           success : function (response) {
               this.trigger("something", "payload");
           }
         });
    }
});
```

It may be the case that the `context` attribute was added in a recent version of jQuery, and it wasn't available before. But this is (in my opinion) the best way to do it.